# Make clicking on a tab character change the caret properly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

In most text editors that are considered decent, clicking on a tab character (`\t`) changes the caret to either the left or the right of the character, depending on the position clicked on.

An example being illustrated below:

[image: Left][image: Right]

The left image shows that, if I'd click, the caret would be to the left of the character. The right one shows that if I were to click, my caret would be at the right of the character.

In my editor, the caret only changes when the cursor is actually placed between two characters. I have been trying to change properties in my `TabStop`s but none of that seemed to work.

The question being: how do I make my tab character clicking respond properly to the cursor position?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you use JEditorPane instance.

Actually it depends on EditorKit you use. For the simplest case you can try to override

```
public int viewToModel(float x, float y, Shape a, Position.Bias[] biasReturn)
```

Method of LabelView class. Actually it returns position in model (caret) for the clicked position (x, y).

If you use HTMLEditorKit it would be much more difficult.

Comment: Well, I'm actually using JTextPane. Overriding [viewToModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#viewToModel(java.awt.Point)) doesn't work - strangely, it isn't called at all. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Do you override view? or JTextPane's method?

Comment: @StanislavL please whats wrong with this code (see my deleted post here)

Comment: @mKorbel For me nothing wrong. It still provides default behaviour.

Comment: @Bart Pelle by default there aren't any other thoughts, you have to post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded valuse for JTextComponent in local variable